# Extracting unique, case insensitive strings from a vector using std::unique_copy

Tags: c++, boost, stl

**The Problem**

Consider the following vectors:

```
std::vector<std::string> extensions;

extensions.push_back(".cpp");
extensions.push_back(".CPP");
extensions.push_back(".h");
extensions.push_back(".H");

std::vector<std::string> caselessUniqueExtensions;
```

Copy the contents of extensions into caselessUniqueExtensions, but discard all unique extensions, ignoring case.  (I.e. the result should have two elements - one of either `.cpp` or `.CPP`, and one of either `.h` and `.H`.)

**The Question**

There are obviously many ways to do this, some more effecient than others, and some more readable than others.  One such way I thought may work is the following:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/compare.hpp>

...

std::unique_copy(
  extensions.begin(), extensions.end(),
  caselessUniqueExts.begin(),
  boost::is_iequal());
```

However, it fails to compile using MSVS2010:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(626): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(2211) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Elem std::_Maklocchr<_Elem>(char,_Elem *,const std::_Locinfo::_Cvtvec &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(2210) : while compiling class template member function 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> std::ctype<std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>>::do_widen(char) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale(261) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ctype<_Elem>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale(259) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Elem std::toupper<T1>(_Elem,const std::locale &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>              T1=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(2042) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::algorithm::is_iequal::operator ()<std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>>(const T1 &,const T2 &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>,
1>              T1=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>              T2=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(2070) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Unique_copy<_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,_OutIt,_Pr,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
1>              _InIt=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *,
1>              _Pr=boost::algorithm::is_iequal,
1>              _FwdIt=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(2094) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Unique_copy1<std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>*,_OutIt,_Pr>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr,std::tr1::true_type)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>,
1>              _Pr=boost::algorithm::is_iequal,
1>              _InIt=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\stv04463\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pgp sandbox\pgp sandbox\main.cpp(64) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::unique_copy<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,boost::algorithm::is_iequal>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
1>              _Pr=boost::algorithm::is_iequal
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(593): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'unsigned char'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(2229) : see reference to function template instantiation 'char std::_Maklocbyte<std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>>(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>,const std::_Locinfo::_Cvtvec &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(2225) : while compiling class template member function 'char std::ctype<_Elem>::_Donarrow(_Elem,char) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
```

Am I missing some basic understanding here, or should it not be possible to combine `std::unique_copy` with `boost::is_iequal`?

I am aware of the alternatives - I'd like to know why I'm getting this compiler error.

Comment: Can't you use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead? With one set having a case insensitive compare function?

Comment: Note: Compiles fine with `gcc 4.7`.

Comment: I 've never used `boost::is_iequal`, but the documentation for [`is_equal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/is_equal.html) sounds troubling. At least it gives me the impression that it tries to cast the arguments to `unsigned char` and compare for case-insensitive equality based on the locale using `==`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Yep, I could, there are many other alternatives too.  But I'd like to understand why this doesn't work if at all possible.

Comment: @Jon - For the uninitiated amongst us, why is that troubling?

Comment: @JimmidyJoo: Because it wouldn't work on `std::string`. But really, it's me who is uninitiated here. It's perfectly possible that I totally got the wrong picture (plus, I didn't read the source).

Comment: @Jon - I just gave interjay the accepted answer, but really you said it first.  Thanks.

Comment: @JimmidyJoo: I 'm happy enough that I didn't make a fool of myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boost::is_iequal` predicate is meant to be used on single characters, not on an entire string like you're doing.

Unfortunately the Boost String Algorithms documentation is not the best, but you can see this specified [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.compare_hpp): "Defines element comparison predicates", where "element" refers to the string characters.

Internally, `boost::is_iequal` calls `std::toupper` on its arguments, and this can only work on characters.